# How can I send data to another page without javascript, jquery, or an HTML form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm very new to web programming and everything I learn I basically learn from looking up documentation online. I have a website running a type of game with an inventory and such. I can't seem to think of a clean way of giving items to the user. It currently uses a JavaScript function, but I realized the user could just call the function from the URL bar and exploit the system.

On a given page, this is the code that calls for an item to be given. The user will click a button like the "Get Hat" button, and will be redirected to another page:

```
<script>
    function giveitem(name, quant)
    {
        document.getElementById("itemnamefield").value=name;
        document.getElementById("itemquantfield").value=quant;
        document.itemform.submit();
    }
</script>
<form id="itemform" name="itemform" action="./itemget.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="itemnamefield" name="itemnamefield" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="itemquantfield" name="itemquantfield" value="">
</form>    
<input type="button" onClick="javscript: giveitem('Hat',1);" value="Get Hat"><br>
```

itemget.php then executes this function using the post data from the previous page. $id is the user's ID number stored in a cookie, $name is the title of the item, $quant is the desired quantity of the items.

```
function additem($id, $name, $quant){
        include 'sqlconnect.php';
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id='$id' AND name='$name'");
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE inventory SET quant=quant+'$quant' WHERE id='$id' AND name='$name'");
        }
        else{
            $subresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM itemdef WHERE name='$name'");
            $subrow = mysqli_fetch_array($subresult);
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO inventory (id, quant, name) VALUES ('$id', '$quant', '$subrow[name]')");
        }
    }
```

itemget.php then displays what items the user received.
So I can't use javascript because that's exploitable. I'm not really intent on using jquery or anything besides standard HTML and PHP (I'm trying to keep it simple because I'm so inexperienced). Is my only alternative to create a new form for every "give x item" button?

Comment: no javascript no forms no jquery? answer: magic

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript, forms, or just simple hyperlinks.

The trick is to let the server know which possibilities the user has. So when you generate the page, you can store in the user's session on the server that you generated the 'get hat' link, so 'get hat' therefor is a valid command.

If you receive a command that is not valid, the user may be cheating, or they clicked 'back' and executed a command from an outdated page. Anyway, you can then ignore the command or display a message instead.

So the trick is to keep the validation on the server. That way, they cannot cheat, because everything other than the commands you provided are blocked.

So talking techniques, you can just write the game logic and session handling in PHP and use plain HTML (hyperlinks) to render the commands. If you like, you can use Javascript/JQuery or forms as well, if you think it is easier or makes your gameplay better. As long as you do the checking on the server, you should be fine.

Comment: So I could leave it as it is and on the page with the "Get X Item" button, I could add a session variable with the allowed items and quantities, then on the confirmation page, I could check if the item sent by the JavaScript function is within any of the bounds of the session variable, then clear the session variable so that it can't be sent again... Does that sound feasible?

Comment: Rather, I could set the session variable to whatever item options are available, and then the JavaScript function would simply submit a number representing which group of available items the user selected. Then clear the session variable on the confirmation page.

Answer (score 0):

Small example. When you send data to a .php file for the information be processed further, always, and I mean always be panicked(not like bad panic, but just be carefull) and don't trust user info. If you know that the variable $x is supposed to be only integer, then use an if condition to make sure it is an integer so bad/malicious data won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Sessions initialized by `<?php session_start(); ?>`, then you can store information stored on server referenced by a cookie with a session id.

For example don't store user's id in a cookie, use sessions: `<?php $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1; ?>`

Then, for example you can store available items in that session, too.

```
game.com/view-x.php

<?php
session_start();
...
$_SESSION['items_available'] = array('hat', 'shoe');
?>
```

When for example a user requests a an item via html form, link, ...:

```
game.com/item-add.php?item=stone

<?php
session_start();
...
if (in_array($_GET['item'], $_SESSION['items_available'])) {
  ..
}
else {
  // 'stone' is not an available item
}
...
```